# SAM-BA monitor problem

Tags: arm, arm7

I tried [SAM-BA monitor](http://www.atmel.com/tools/ATMELSAM-BAIN-SYSTEMPROGRAMMER.aspx) for atmel at91samxxxx chips

I'm working with non-atmel board using at91sam7s128 , I tried the monitor program with board option : at91sam7s128 and noboard but neither of them works they are not responding ?!

My computer recognized the chip and I tried the board on both windows xp and linux :

In linux I have this when I put in terminal lsusb :

**Bus 005 Device 008: ID 03eb:6124 Atmel Corp. at91sam SAMBA bootloader**

and in windows I installed the driver and board is recognized in serial port category .

So if my computer recognize the chip and SAM-BA therefor do every thing must be ok ?

I also tried [SAM_I_AM](http://claymore.engineer.gvsu.edu/~steriana/Software/Sam_I_Am/index.html) ,it successfully open a communication with my board using 'open command' but when I give a command like 'info usb' it gives me 'Error: SAM-BA not responding'

in my board I used some estimate value , in specific :

- I used 31 ohm resistors instead of 27 ohm for DP-DM .
- I used 12pf capacitors instead of 15pf for DP-DM .
- I used 1.47k resistor in pll RC loop instead of 1.5k .which maybe
  sounds good as what the [pll calculator](http://www.at91.com/forum/viewtopic.php/f,4/t,986/?time=1370858238) says .
- and I used 12pf load capacitors instead of 10pf load capacitors for 18.432MH crystal .

and this schematic shows all parts related to usb in my board :

[image]

is there any thing could help me to indicate the problem ?  also I have some fears about [FDN360P](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD/FDN340P.pdf) maybe it is slow in switching , but datasheet didn't said any things on how fast pulling up will be .

Comment: I doubt this is a hardware issue, since enumeration has obviously completed without errors. IIRC, SAMBA works over both USB and UART. Unfortunately, the protocols differ, so using UART-over-USB will confuse the PC client to use the wrong protocol. You can either try UART, or you can try my implementation of the client: http://tasssadar.github.io/Lorris/index.html (no guarantees, I only used it once).

Comment: @avakar GREAT ! thank you it works with your client :) . I tried V# (which gives me 2004 version ) command and I tried O20001,1# then a read command o20001,# which gives me 0x01 as result . 
the question is why my board works only with you client ?!

Comment: hmmmm , it seem that I have a hardware problem , it works for one time .

Comment: I tested my board with a program under linux called freesba , I could switch between xmodem and raw protocol but neither could communicate with sam-ba . I also succeeded to open connection but sam-ba doesn't response .

Comment: So what happens if you use Lorris, select "Programmer", choose the connection and set "programmer type" to "atsam"? Is it able to fetch the chip's details? (Try clicking "read fuses" or "read".)

Comment: "sam-ba not responding" , I think It soo clear that I have a failure in usb connection that make the lorris successes in read and write once and fails other times .

Comment: I modified 33ohm to 28 ohm which is accepted and 1.37k in pll to 1.45k which is in the range .

I still have this question my external crystal load capacitance is 18p , the load capacitance  of XIN ,XOUT of sam7s128 is in range 17~23 pF but datasheet said that external CAP must be no more than 10pF .

So dose  external CAP 12pF could make frequency wronge and so make SAM-BA don't respond ?

Comment: for visitors of this question :
anyone had the same problem and need a solution  , I will continue discussing here : http://www.at91.com/forum/viewtopic.php/f,15/t,21653/

Answer (score 1):

You need to erase the chip to put the GPNVM Bit to 0 to boot from the ROM again.
It worked only once because maybe after loading your soft to the flash, the GPNVM Bit was set to 1 (1 means boot from flash).